# Seeing web traffic from my C# app in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

I'd like to watch requests and responses sent from my C# program that uses System.Net.WebRequest in Fiddler. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you haven't tried yet?

Comment: Thank you very much. I should've looked closer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

Open Fiddler, start using your application and you will see entries appear in the Web Sessions table. Click these and look at what is being sent in the Inspectors tabs

Comment: If you don't see the requests, try starting Fiddler before your application. If that doesn't work, see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET